# no known conversion from 'struct Scene' to 'struct Scene *'

Tags: c++

What does this mean? I was coding with the goal of reading a text file and inputing the data into my array of structs to hold floats.

I'm pretty sure I initialized the structs correctly, but maybe I didn't.

```
int obj,objnum,linenum, line;



int main() { 
struct Scene objects[objnum];

InitScene(objnum, linenum, "text.txt", objects[objnum]);

return 0;

}
```

This is the function cpp file, I'm not sure how I would add a pointer to this...

```
void InitScene(int objnum, int linenum, string filename, struct Scene objects[objnum]) {
  ifstream myfile(filename);
  myfile >> objnum; 
   objects[objnum];
  
  
    for (int i = 0; i < objnum; i++){
      myfile >> linenum;
      for (int j = 0; j < linenum; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
              myfile >> objects[i].Object[j][k];
            }
      }
    }
  myfile.close();
  }
```

This is my header file.

```
struct Scene {
    
    float Object[20][6];
    
};


void InitScene(int n, int line, string x, struct Scene a[]);
```

Please help! I'm not understanding what I'm missing.

Comment: You create the 0-size array `objects[objnum]`, then attempt to access it's first element.

Comment: `struct Scene objects[objnum];` is not allowed in Standard C++ . The dimension of a C-style array must be known at compile-time.

Comment: The name of the array is "objects", not "objects[objnum]". Indexing with the size does not mean "the entire array", it attempts to access a single array element that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

The error message means you're converting a single `Scene` value to a `Scene` *pointer*. This usually indicates a typo. Indeed, looking at the call from `main`:

```
InitScene(objnum, linenum, "text.txt", objects[objnum]);
//                                     ^ here
```

Right above, `objects[objnum]` is a `Scene` value, but your function expects an array (*i.e* a pointer). This is exactly what the error message says.

Change the call to:

```
InitScene(objnum, linenum, "text.txt", objects);
```